# Type hierarchy + optional field

Tags: java, design-patterns, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm working on a bit of Java and I'm not quite sure how to solve this problem, at least not without ugliness that I'd like to avoid. I have a parent abstract class, let's say Item. Item has three subclasses, ItemA, which is concrete, and another abstract class, ItemB, which itself has two concrete child classes, ItemB1 and ItemB2. ItemA is just a stub and may not need to exist if Item itself can become concrete, but I wasn't sure if the stub was needed or not depending on the solution. All of these must inherit from Item or a parent interface as they'll be sitting in a number of Collections.

Now, we have this hierarchy of Items. The fun part is that the Items have an optional object field, let's say it's an object called Functionality. Any of the concrete classes can potentially have a Functionality object, but some would not. It needs to be on some, but shouldn't exist on others. I'd like to avoid slapping it in Item and nullchecking all the time to see if it's there. It's possible, but strikes me as being a bit ugly. I don't think splitting up the hierarchy into two separate trees is really feasible either since I'd largely be duplicating a bunch of classes with one piece of extra data.

What to do in a case like this? I initially thought of using a decorator, but that would mean typechecking like mad to see if it was a FunctionalityDecoratedItem or somesuch every time I needed to see if it has the Functionality field, and I'm already doing a bit of typechecking to determine what to do with different subtypes of Item. Maybe I'm just nitpicking on this (I sometimes have a tendency to get hung up on small details) or maybe there's an obvious solution that my nose is blocking, but I'm hoping that I've just missed a pattern or technique that could implement this cleanly.

Answer (score 2):

Define an interface. Some classes implement the interface, others do not. You can use `instanceof` to check if an object implements an interface at run time.

Comment: I should probably mention that they all need to implement a common interface as there will be multiple occasions where Collections of the interface will be used. Declaring a single interface and splitting it into two sets, one with Functionality and one without with another pair of interfaces will wind up with a lot of duplication and make maintainability more difficult.